# Android device running 5.1 does not support work profiles

Tags: android

It was my understanding that work profiles are supported on devices running Android 5.0 + later. I have a tablet running Android 5.1 and it does not allow me to set up a work profile.

[image]

How do I check if a device is compatible with work profiles and what makes it compatible.

Comment: Only a handful of devices support Work profile on Android. What device are you using? Also make sure it's available in your country https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6270910?hl=en&ref_topic=6151012

Comment: On your device, go to Settings > Accounts. If you have a work profile it's listed in the Work section.

Comment: In theory it should work, but it depends on the method you use, check this chary https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devices#Key_provisioning_differences_across_android_releases